# How to send login payload to a form using relative URL for post method?

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** a website which needs login. The problem is that the url of the login form is something like this:

```
/customer/guest/index
```

The question is how may I send the login information to this post method?

P.S: I'm trying to use method mentioned in [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-data-behind-site-logins-with-python-ee0676f523ee) article.

**UPDATE: Here is the code I'm using**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv


# Start the session
session = requests.Session()

# Create the payload
payload = {'CustomerLogin[email]':'<USERNAME>',
          'CustomerLogin[password]':'<PASSWORD>',
          'csrf_token': '<TOKEN>'
         }

# Post the payload to the site to log in
s = session.post(" https://avangemail.net/customer/guest/index", data=payload)
print('Logging in...')

# Navigate to the next page and scrape the data
s = session.get('https://avangemail.net/customer/lists/all-subscribers')

print('Getting information...')
print(s.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
tbody = table.find('tbody')

headers = [td.text for td in thead.select("tr td td")]

filename = 'avang-export'
with open(r'.'+filename+'.csv', "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerows([[td.text for td in row.find_all("td")] for row in tbody.select("tr")])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    data= {
              '_username':'[YOUR_USERNAME]', 
              '_password':'[YOUR_PASSWORD]'
          }
```

then pass it to post method

```
response = requests.post(
    your_url,
    data=data
)
```

Comment: problem is that the URL is not an absolute one. The requests asks for url schema.

Comment: What's the URL of the website? do you only have this: /customer/guest/index ? Then I don't think is possible to do anything with just this path...

Comment: Here is the login link : https://avangemail.net/customer/guest/index

Comment: try: s = session.post("https://avangemail.net/customer/guest/index", data=payload) while passing on the data dictionary your username and password

Comment: Not  logging. I will update the question with the code I'm using.

Comment: okk print response.status_code and see what is the error about.

Comment: I did it like this: 
d = session.post(" https://avangemail.net/customer/guest/index", data=payload) and then print(d.status_code) 
the code is 400

Comment: Try with http: 'https ://avangemail.net/customer/guest/index'

Comment: With the space between https and : it says: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'https ://avangemail.net/customer/guest/index': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://https ://avangemail.net/customer/guest/index?

Comment: No. I just put the space in betweeen so u can see the https else it wouldn't show on my comment.

Comment: Yes. With the https at the begging the response code is the same.